# Selection an item from a python list

Tags: python, list, menu

I have created a list of names numbered 1-10. I want the user to be able to enter a number (1-10) to select a name.  I have the following code but as yet cant get it to work. I'm new to python. thanks for the help

```
def taskFour():

    1 == Karratha_Aero
    2 == Dampier_Salt
    3 == Karratha_Station
    4 == Roebourne_Aero
    5 == Roebourne
    6 == Cossack
    7 == Warambie
    8 == Pyramid_Station
    9 == Eramurra_Pool
    10 == Sherlock


    print''
    print 'Choose a Base Weather Station'
    print 'Enter the corresponding station number'
    selection = int(raw_input('Enter a number from: 1 to 10'))
    if selection == 1:
        selectionOne()
    elif selection == 2:
        selectionTwo()
    elif selection == 3:
        selectionThree()
```

Comment: you need to understand python's basic syntax rules.

Comment: Is that your complete Python code to do what you want? Because there is mismatches of Python syntax.

Comment: the elif statements continue to 10, is that what you mean?

Comment: You don't have definitions for the `selection*` functions shown here, for one thing.  Also, the fact that this is called `taskFour` implies there are at least tasks 1 through 3 as well, and some sort of runner that is calling these things.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are following an anti-pattern. What are you going to do when there are one million different stations, or multiple data per station?

You can't have `selectionOne()` all the way through to `selectionOneMillion()` done manually.

How about something like this:

```
stations = {'1': "Karratha_Aero",
            '2': "Karratha_Station",
            '10': "Sherlock"}

user_selection = raw_input("Choose number: ")

print stations.get(user_selection) or "No such station"
```

Input/Output:

```
1 => Karratha_Aero
10 => Sherlock
5 => No such station
```

Comment: Nice folding in of the error handling.

Answer (score 2):

First, you need a real list. What you currently have (`1 == Name`) is neither a list, or valid syntax (unless you have variables named after each of the names). Change your list to this:

```
names = ['Karratha_Aero', 'Dampier_Salt', 'Karratha_Station', 'Roebourne_Aero', 'Roebourne', 'Cossack', 'Warambie', 'Pyramid_Station', 'Eramurra_Pool', 'Sherlock']
```

Then, change your bottom code to this:

```
try:
  selection = int(raw_input('Enter a number from: 1 to 10'))
except ValueError:
  print "Please enter a valid number. Abort."
  exit
selection = names[selection - 1]
```

`selection` will then be the name of the selection of the user.

Comment: Should probably wrap the `int(raw_input...)` in a `try/except` too to handle the case where the user inputs a value that can't be coerced to an int.

Comment: @sr2222: Thanks. I'll do that.

Comment: thanks guys ill see how I go. should of realised it was not a real list.

Comment: @MarkKearney: Hope it works.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working code for you:

```
def taskFour():
    myDictionary={'1':'Name1','2':'Name2','3':'Name3'}
    print''
    print 'Choose a Base Weather Station'
    print 'Enter the corresponding station number'
    selection = str(raw_input('Enter a number from: 1 to 10'))
    if selection in myDictionary:
        print myDictionary[selection]
        #Call your function with this name "selection" instead of print myDictionary[selection] 

taskFour()
```

Comment: so many options, I will have a play about. so far ive got it working ok but I think I can make it a bit more simple. thanks eveyone